# Given $A\cap B$, $A\cap C$ and $B\cap C$, what is $A\cap (B\cap C)=$?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we know about $A\cap B$, $A\cap C$, and $B\cap C$.
Here, each set is a binary representation of a decimal number, hence each set includes 0's and 1's with specific positions or order. The intersection here means the 1's in these binary numbers that overlap at some positions. We are interested in the size of the set, meaning the number of overlapping positions with value 1.
Hence, the set is defined as the coordinate of 1's in each binary number.
Note that the size of these sets is actually Hamming weight or the number of 1's.

We have some extra information as well . We know that $|A\cap B|=x$,  $|A\cap C|=x$ or $x+1$,  $|B\cap C|=x$ or $x+1$ if $|A\cap C|=x+1$. You can consider all $x$.
How can we find $|A\cap (B\cap C)|=$?

Example 1: When $|A\cap B|=x$,  $|A\cap C|=x$,  $|B\cap C|=x$

A = 1 0 1 1 = {0, 1, 3}

B = 1 1 0 1 = {0, 2, 3}

C= 1 1 1 0 = {1, 2, 3}

$A\cap B = \{0, 3\}$

$A\cap C = \{1, 3\}$

$B\cap C = \{2, 3\}$

$A\cap B\cap C = \{3\}$

Here, 0, 1, 2, and 3 refer to the position of every bit where 0 refers to the rightmost bit (LSB) and 3 refers to the leftmost bit (MSB)

For many examples like this one when $|A\cap B|=x$,  $|A\cap C|=x$,  $|B\cap C|=x$, I am getting  $|A\cap (B\cap C)|=x-1$.

Example 2: When $|A\cap B|=x$,  $|A\cap C|=x+1$,  $|B\cap C|=x+1$

A = 1 0 1 1 = {0, 1, 3}

B = 1 1 0 1 = {0, 2, 3}

C= 1 1 1 1 = {0, 1, 2, 3}

$A\cap B = \{0, 3\}$

$A\cap C = \{0, 1, 3\}$

$B\cap C = \{0, 2, 3\}$

$A\cap B\cap C = \{0, 3\}$

For many examples like this one when $|A\cap B|=x$,  $|A\cap C|=x+1$,  $|B\cap C|=x+1$, I am getting  $|A\cap (B\cap C)|=x$.

I would appreciate any tip or help to solve or understand this problem better. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Knowing the pairwise intersections doesn't in general give you enough information to get the three-way intersection. I suggest you try to find an example to illustrate this.

Comment: I don't understand how $011=\{\,0,1,3\,\}$, nor the other two similar equations.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, you are right. Sorry. I missed the MSB. Basically, 0, 1, 2, and 3 refer to the position of every bit where 0 refers to the right most bit (LSB) and 3 refers to the MSB.

Comment: OK, so, you have found an example where all the pairwise intersections have two elements, and the three-way intersection has one. Now can you find an example where the pairwise intersections all have two elements, and the three-way has none? or two?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I just added. Please see above.

Comment: But I wanted all pairwise intersections to have two elements.

Comment: Well, in my problem as mentioned above, we will never face such a case. Due to the constraints, among the three binary numbers, only one may have a weight $x+1$, the other two always have weight $x$.

Comment: Huh? You have given an example, your 1st example, in which all pairwise intersections have two elements. How can you say it never happens?

Comment: I meant that. It is not possible to have the pairwise intersections of two elements (for all), and the three-way has none or two elements. This is against our assumptions in the definition of the problem. Isn't it?

Comment: The assumptions are only about the pairwise intersections, and your question is what you can conclude about the three-way intersection (by which I mean the intersection of all three). And I'm suggesting that you can't say much about the three-way, just from knowing all the pairwise numbers. In particular, even if the pairwise intersections are all size two, the three-way intersection could be empty, or have exactly one element, or have two elements. You have produced an example where the three-way has one element; I'm challenging you to find examples of the other possibilities.

Comment: So, how are we doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $|A\cap B| = a,$ $|B\cap C| = b,$ $|C\cap A|=c$ and $|A\cap B\cap C|=x$.

Also, let
$$A = \{1,2,3,4\}, \ \ B = \{2,3,4,5\}, \ \ C = \{\color{red}4,6,7,8\} $$
Then
$$
A\cap B = \{2,3,4\}, \ \ B\cap C = \{4\}, \ \ A\cap C = \{4\} \\
a=3, \ \  b=c=1 \\
A\cap B\cap C = \{4\} \implies \boxed{x = 1}$$

Now, let
$$A = \{1,2,3,4\}, \ \ B = \{2,3,4,5\}, \ \ C = \{\color{red}5,6,7,1\} $$
Then,
$$
A\cap B = \{2,3,4\}, \ \ B\cap C = \{5\}, \ \ A\cap C = \{1\} \\ 
a=3, \ \  b=c=1 \\
A\cap B\cap C = \emptyset \implies \boxed{x=0}$$

Notice that the same triplets $(a,b,c)$ led to two different results ($x=1$ and $x=0$) from which we can deduce that there is no such formula in general.

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. What if we know that $|A\cap B|=x$,  $|A\cap C|=x$,  $|B\cap C|=x$ or $2x$? Note that the sets are the coordinates of 1's in the binary numbers, so we know the relationship b/w them.

Comment: Why don't you construct an example or two to test it, @Persian? You will learn a lot more that way, than by getting someone elese to construct examples for you.

Comment: @Gerry-Myerson, I have already added an example to the main question at the top. If not sufficient, I can add more.

Comment: What @VIVID said is true in general, but here we have some constraints as mentioned in the edited question.

Comment: It's not nice, Persian, to change the question after a user has posted an answer. Better to rollback the edit, accept VIVID's answer, and post a new question (but link each question to the other).

Comment: Sorry. I agree. I will do it next time. Actually, the question is the same, I just provided more details.

Comment: VIVID's answer was correct before you provided more details, but it's not correct after you provided more details. VIVID didn't change the answer; you changed the question. The question is not the same. You changed it.

Comment: @PersianEngineer I agree with Gerry Myerson, probably you should ask a new question with your new constraints added and link to this Q&A so that people do not spend time on discussing what has been discussed here.